# PresentViewController after UIImage filter not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

I have to apply blur effect like iOS 7 when i am presenting a modal view controller so that the background is clear and can see the blur effect. Following is the code i am using, but i need to present this view controller after a timer is finished. But its just showing a blur image in the background and not presenting the view controller.

```
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
imgView.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];
[[[GCAppDelegate instance]window] addSubview:imgView];
UIImage *image= [self getScreenShotOfWindow];

messageViewController = (GCMessageSelectionViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GCMessageSelectionViewController"];
[self presentViewController:messageViewController animated:YES completion:^(){
    //put your code here
    imgView.image = image;
}];
```

Comment: 1. Check if your animation really finishes (put a breakpoint there)
2. Check if controller that you want to present is not nil
3. Are you doing this code in your ViewController or somewhere else?

Comment: I am doing this code in the viewController only. and its finishes the animation.

Comment: Good, now question #2, please.

Comment: Yes it is not nil, i checked it with the break point.

Comment: Hmm... Try to add non-NULL completion block to message controller presentation and set a breakpoint there.
Also, try adding your image not to window, but to rootViewController's view.

Comment: Declare this object in interface. GCMessageSelectionViewController *messageViewController;

Comment: if i present it from the root view controller it shows some black background and weird animation.

Comment: Declared object in interface, still same problem, shows only blur background but no modal view controller.

Comment: Tried with above changed code, it presents the view controller but in completion block as soon as i set the image the view controller disappears and just a blur image is shown.

Comment: In the above code, you are already presented one view controller then how can you display imageview?

Answer (score 0):

messageViewController is probably pushed but is covered by the blur image.

try assigning imgView to messageViewController's view.